# Vim inserting white spaces after accentuations and other special characters on Mac

Tags: macos, vim, osx-mavericks, character-encoding

If I write the following text on vim:

```
Tís teçxt contãins spécial charàctérs
```

I will get:

```
Tí s teç xt contã ins spé cial cha?| cté rs
```

This wasn't happening before, when I had Mountain Lion. I've upgraded to Mavericks a while ago, but I was only writing code on vim and didn't notice if this was a change due to the system upgrade. Anyway, this also happens if I write text on other server vims using my computer.

This doesn't happen when I am not on vim.

It does not seems related to the vim version, as I've changed it and on both of them it has the same problem.

I am using the character encoding as utf-8 on the terminal preferences and setting vim fileenconding as

```
set fileencoding=utf8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen when you invoke vim this way: `vim -u NONE -U NONE --noplugin -N`

Comment: No, but I discovered another thing: my macbook is in german, and I had on my macvim the following lines: `set langmenu=en_US
let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim`. I have commented those lines and now it is not using space anymore… But it gets problematic after I get out of insert mode (it get confused with the characters, if I try to delete one of them, it makes everything a mess).

Comment: Ohhhh sorry!!! It was missing the set encoding=utf8 as well! Thank you for your help @Heptite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was missing:

```
set encoding=utf8
```

on my `.vimrc`.